# What each stack element does

Tags: geoext, geoexplorer, graph, online

I'm using the opengeo stack, and want to double check my understanding of each element.

- PostGIS - The database for storing my data
- GeoServer - The link between the online part / the database

Here's where I am not fully sure:

- Geoexplorer, viewing, editing data visually in the POST database
- Client SDK - The same as geoexploer but I have to add the functionality?

If I want to add Graphs to the map, i.e. the user clicks on a point, how would I go about that? using SDK and the GeoEXT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoExplorer is a sample application built with the Client SDK, which provides useful functionality like styling layers and publishing maps. Use the Client SDK to build your own applications. You may want to follow the [tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/apps/) to learn how to built your own applications on top of and components for the SDK. Your custom components will use OpenLayers and GeoExt.